# Sitecore 9 eLearning TAC.Sitecore.Abstraction errors with code in Student resource file SitecoreItem.cs

Tags: unit-testing, training

In Module 5,  I am getting an error on the Creating a Breadcrumb Component. I brought in the TAC.Sitecore.Abstractions project like the directions say and I added the reference for it in my event.tac.local project. When I try to build the TAC.Sitecore.Abstractions project, I am receiving the following errors:

[image: Sitecore 9.0 errors]

I have tried to Google these various errors and have not been able to find any solution.

Here is the SitecoreItem.cs file:

[image: Code from SitecoreItem.cs]

I appreciate any help that anyone can give to help resolve these errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @SoccerZortz, welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange, glad you found us. Looking at your screenshots, this looks like maybe something isn't set right in the project. But we would need to diagnose more, because of that it might be better to open a chat here on SSE or head over to https://sitecorechat.slack.com/ and ask there, or the community forums at https://community.sitecore.net/ - SSE is not an easy place for conversation and diagnosing things, so you'll probably get more help at the other sites.

Comment: The error seems to be due the [expression bodied method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx) on Line 29. Most likely you missing a package reference, check if your project is using `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check reference of Microsoft.Net.Compilers
remove obj folders (clean solution build)
remove any missing reference and add again. (Reference generated error or appear as warning)
Make sure you aren't missing any reference in any project

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That seemed to fix it. Thank  you @jammykam too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a missing references issue.

Check your `TestItem.cs` file. You have mismatched `{` and `}` brackets, likely missing the last closing `}`.  Once that is sorted out, `TAC.Sitecore.Abstractions` will compile correctly.

The remaining errors are just followups from this initial error.

Comment: The code is fine, it's using Expression Bodies Methods introduced in C# 6.0 which is why the lack of `{}` looks weird: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx